# Inequality of exponential function compared to its rational (Padé) approximation

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, pade-approximation

In the context of studying the convexity of the real function (which is not [DCP-convex](https://dcp.stanford.edu/analyzer?expr=inv_pos(1%20-%20exp(-inv_pos(x)))) but really "looks" convex)

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{1-\exp(-1/x)}, \text{for } x\geq 0,$$

after some manipulation of the second derivative, I end up having to study the sign of the expression:

$$e^{-z} (z+2) + z-2$$

which should be positive iff $g$ is convex. However, I wasn't able to bound it directly. Also, the positivity of that expression is equivalent to the following inequality which compares the $\exp$ function with its rational approximation (more precisely its [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant#Examples) of order $(1,1)$):

$$ e^{-x} \geq \frac{2-x}{2+x} = \frac{1-x/2}{1+x/2}, x\geq 0$$

Visually, I have no doubts about the validity of this inequality (see graph below) on the positive domain, but I cannot find how to proove it. I haven't find it in the list of [inequalities involving the Exp function on functions.wolfram.com](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/29/).

Perhaps I should compare the series expansions?

[image: Plot of the Exp function compared to its Padé approximant]